# Sending email using Gmail on Windows server 2008

Tags: gmail

I write a small c# console run on my windows server 2008 (port 587, enable ssl, smtp.gmail.com). It can't send email using Gmail. The result is "Failure sending email". But it can run on another windows server 2008 and from my laptop. So what is missing config on my server?

I have just checked:

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
Connecting To smtp.gmail.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 587: Connect failed
```

How can I config to pass this on my server?

Comment: Please show the code you are using to send email.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the solution. Simply change port 587 -> 25. That's all.